# Change Angular material overlay position dynamically after attaching

Tags: angular, angular-material, overlay, angular-material2, angular-cdk

Have a number of Overlays that need to re-position after `window-resize` event.

The current initialy configured `PositionStrategy` *has logic that is dependent on outside variables* to align Overalys similar to CSS Grid / Flexbox behavior.

This [material2 github issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1430#issuecomment-455034167) seems to indicate can only use `OverlayRef.dispose()` =>  `OverlayRef.create()`.

Is there any solution that meets the following:

- Can update position with non static values.
- Does not destroy the component instance.

Preferably able to be called from service and not `OverlayRef`'s component instance.

**Edit 1 for clarity:**
Given the following `PositionStrategy`, `OverlayRef.updatePosition()` seems to not apply as need to re-calculate px.  **Note* `window.innerWidth`

```
      private setChannelPosition(): PositionStrategy {
        const chatWidth = 280;
        const chatSpace = 5;
        const distanceFromEdge = 80;

        const existingModalCount = this.channelModals.size;
        const numModalsCanFit = 
           Math.floor((window.innerWidth - 2 * distanceFromEdge) / (chatWidth + chatSpace));
        const distFromRight = 
           distanceFromEdge + ((existingModalCount % numModalsCanFit) * (chatWidth + chatSpace));
        return this.overlay.position().global().bottom('0px').right(`${distFromRight}px`);
      }
```

**Edit 2:**
The modals are transient..  So a solution with `flexibleConnectedTo()` doesn't seem to apply as any modal may or may not be closed by user in any order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you only call `setChannelPosition()` once when making the `OverlayConfig`, like:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  private overlayRef: OverlayRef;

  constructor(
    private overlay: Overlay
  ) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createOverlay();
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize')
  public onResize(): void {
    this.overlayRef.updatePosition();
  }

  private setChannelPosition(): PositionStrategy {
    const chatWidth = 280;
    const chatSpace = 5;
    const distanceFromEdge = 80;

    const existingModalCount = this.channelModals.size;
    const numModalsCanFit =  Math.floor((window.innerWidth - 2 * distanceFromEdge) / (chatWidth + chatSpace));
    const distFromRight = distanceFromEdge + ((existingModalCount % numModalsCanFit) * (chatWidth + chatSpace));
    return this.overlay.position().global().bottom('0px').right(`${distFromRight}px`);
  }

  private createOverlay() {
    const config = new OverlayConfig({
      positionStrategy: this.setChannelPosition()
    });
    this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create(config);
    this.overlayRef.attach(/* template or component*/);
  }

}
```

so the line `this.overlay.position().global().bottom('0px').right(`${distFromRight}px`);` only runs once creating a `GlobalPositionStrategy` with bottom 0px and rigth being what ever the value of `distFromRight` was at the time.

`OverlayRef.updatePosition()` calls `PositionStrategy.apply()` which `GlobalPositionStrategy` implements and simply applyies css values based on its properties (in this case being bottom 0px and rigth being what ever the value of `distFromRight` when `setChannelPosition()` ran).

The solution would be to have `PositionStrategy` that recalculates on `PositionStrategy.apply()`.

```
class MyPositionStrategy implements PositionStrategy {
  public apply(): void {
    /* recalculates */
  }
}

const config = new OverlayConfig({
 positionStrategy: instanceOfMyPositionStrategy 
});
```

[ruff example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-position-strategy)

**or**

Change the `PositionStrategy` before calling `OverlayRef.updatePosition()` by calling `OverlayRef.updatePositionStrategy()` *new to angular material 7 I think*.

```
@HostListener('window:resize')
public onResize(): void {
  this.overlayRef.updatePositionStrategy(this.setChannelPosition());
  this.overlayRef.updatePosition();
}
```

So the `setChannelPosition()` runs and `PositionStrategy` changes every time the  window resizes.

[ruff example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/update-position-strategy)

Note:

There was an old solution like

```
@HostListener('window:resize')
public onResize(): void {
  this.overlayRef.getConfig().positionStrategy = this.setChannelPosition();
  this.overlayRef.updatePosition();
}
```

but `getConfig().positionStrategy` is now readonly and doesn't work

Comment: Thx, didn't see `updatePositionStrategy` in version of Material I was using.